# She said/ told me if I wanted to come

Tags: grammar, reported-speech

Why is it grammatically wrong to say:

> She **told** me if I wanted to come.
>
> She **said** if I wanted to come.

I have been told that in this context we must use **ask** rather than *tell* or *say*.

Comment: Do a research in terms of checking the dictionary entries for those verbs and “if”. It should become apparent once you learn the meaning of each.

Comment: @user2684291 this is not basic question.I know those verbs and if.

Comment: As it's stated, it's trivial. Maybe if you described the intended meaning we could determine what the problem is.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the phrases themselves, but really some more context is needed. In the second one, "She said" could be reported speech to someone else, whereas the first is clearly directed at *me*.

Comment: @user3169 I asked this question because it is said that it is not grammatically correct to use the word say and tell in yes/no question or that is if structures as in the examples.Where as we should use only the word to ask

Comment: You should reference where "it is said", and add that point to your question.

Comment: I'm going to vote to re-open because I looked more closely and saw the "reported-speech" tag, and I think someone could explain "She asked **if** I wanted to come" and "She said, 'Do you want to come?'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with

> She asked (me) if I wanted to come.

since it's reporting a **yes/no question** which seems to be an invitation. If that's the case, then I could go with this too

> She invited me to go with her.

We usually use *tell* when we report a statement (rather than a question) indirectly and we use *say* when we want to report something directly. In other words, *use 'say' for **exact quotes*** as in

> She said, "let's dance."

and in indirect reports with 'that' as in

> She said (that) she loved him.